# How to prove that pseudo entropy and topological entropy are the same with only Markov inequality and continuity?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, group-actions, entropy, discrete-dynamical-systems, sofic-groups

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a compact metric space and $f:X\to X$ a homeomorphism. We say $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n})\in X^n$ is a partial $n$ orbit if $f(x_i)=x_{i+1}$. Let $Sep_{\epsilon}(X,\rho_n)$ be the maximal cardinality of an $\epsilon$-separated set of partial $n$ orbits. The (topological) entropy of $(X,f)$ if given by

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\limsup_{n} \log Sep_{\epsilon}(X,\rho_n)$$

where $\rho_n(x,y)=\max_i \rho(x_i,y_i)$

With pseudo entropy I mean calculating entropy using the following definition of pseudo partial orbit:

$(x_1,\ldots,x_{n})$ is an $(n,\delta)$ pseudo partial orbit if

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \rho(f(x_i),x_{i+1})< \delta$$

and the pseudo entropy of $(X,f)$ is given by:

$$ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \inf_{\delta>0}\limsup_{n}\log Sep_{\epsilon}(X,\rho_n)$$

I'm abusing notation here but now the $Sep_\epsilon$ refers to $(n,\delta)$ partial pseudo orbits.

According to Lewis Bowen you can prove that the two quantities are equal using Markov inequality and continuity. I tried to but got stuck, Markov tells us that for a natural number $r<n/2$ we can find a piece of the pseudo partial orbit such that each adjacent term has $\rho(f(x_i),x_{i+1})<r\delta $.

I wanted to prove using this technique because is motivation for the definition of sofic entropy. One can prove this by using much more general results, like sofic entropy for amenable groups being equal to topological entropy for all sofic approximations, but again that would be too much for my purposes.

Comment: Look at this: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2048021

Comment: I've seen it a while a go, the problem is that pseudo orbits here are not averaged as in my case, I can though find a smaller piece of mine that is like the one defined is this paper. Don't know how to proceed.